# Html5 canvas not drawing in Div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Ok. so basically i have a div that i want to load it with a file that has some html5 canvas.
When i load the file on its self it works. The problem is when i load my site normal and press the link to load the same file in the div that i want it doesn't draw.

I use  $('#container').load('mycanvas.html');    with .click event to  load the file

The code below is what is in the mycanvas.html file.

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 150);
    context.lineTo(450, 50);
    context.stroke();
  };

</script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can we see the code for your other page with the #container. Does your browsers console window show any error message?

Comment: I am not getting any errors .. the #container div is '<div id='container'></div>' the page is to huge to post

Comment: Ok - I assume you have jQuery referenced correctly. I suspect it's something to do with window.onload = function()  not running when loaded via jQuery.Load();

Comment: Thanks for your time Dave.. i have removed the onload part from the canvas script and it works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for mycanvas.html.

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  }
</style>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 150);
    context.lineTo(450, 50);
    context.stroke();

</script>
```

Comment: If you're loading this in with ajax, I recommend putting the javascript in a closure so it won't affect the global scope.

Comment: Great point. @Alexander Wrap up the contents up in a function to help prevent the variables `canvas` and `context` interfering with other variables. These don't need to be globally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

above the your javascript code.

Comment: Try removing the window.onload part. I guess the event isn't firing?